# EDB - How do I debug a program with i/o redirection as the arguments?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86

I have an x86 asm program that converts lowercase letters to uppercase. I found it in an assembly pdf and am playing around with it to learn. The program can be invoked like this

```
./uppercaser > in.txt < out.txt
```

I'm attempting to add some form of error checking as an exercise, and as you can imagine for a newbie like me, it's not going well. I wanted to run the program in a debugger to see what is going on, but running it in EDB as is doesn't work, because the program needs input. I've googled how to do this, and apparently

```
edb --run ./uppercaser > in.txt < out.txt
```

Is supposed to do it, yet when I run it like that the program fails to continue executing in the debugger after a few instructions, just like it did when I ran it with no input. So how do I achieve this?

I realize that being very new to assembly and debugging I could simply have a fundamental misunderstanding of how things work, but I am assuming the program stops stepping in the debugger after a few instructions because it's waiting for input and not getting any.

Comment: Check where it stops and why. Maybe it has consumed your `in.txt` already, or it is missing an end of line marker or similar. Also check that it isn't `edb` itself executing your `in.txt`. You could also try launching `edb` without the program then use the `run` command inside `edb`.

Comment: I dont know edb, but when you use gdb (gnu debugger) you need to set some breakpoints in your code to be able to go through it step by step and to look at the register contents. When you simply use run with gdb right from the start, it will run your program without stopping, which is not that useful (But I am new to this, too ;))

Comment: I ended up going the gdb route and running "set args > out.txt < in.txt" from inside gdb, then using stepi to step through it.

Answer (score 2):

edb does *not* make this easy.  It may even be impossible, unfortunately (other than by modifying edb.  It's open source).

If you can pause your program before it does anything, you can attach to an already-running process in whatever terminal, instead of starting a new xterm.

If you want to pipe data into the process, you might use a named pipe.  e.g.

```
   mkfifo   mypipe
   ./testprog < mypipe &           # or not in the background
     # tab over to EDB and attach to testprog
   (echo ...; cat - ) > mypipe     # in a different terminal if you want
```

Obviously use whatever you want to write to the pipe, like `cat file`, or a perl or python one-liner to generate some data.  After it exits, `testprog`'s read system call may get an EOF on stdin; that's why I used a subshell with one redirect that will stay open across echo and `cat` of stdin.

---

edb takes the arg to `--run` and runs it redirected to the tty of an xterm which edb also starts.

I tried a few things, including

```
edb --run ./a.out '<in.txt'
```

That just runs the command with `<in.txt` on its command line.  The debugged program's stdin is coming from the xterm.  Edb apparently doesn't get a shell involved, so you can't use shell meta-characters.

edb's command-line output (in the terminal you run it from, not the xterm it opens) includes:

```
Running Terminal:  "/usr/bin/xterm"
Terminal Args:  ("-title", "edb output", "-hold", "-e", "sh", "-c", "tty > /tmp/edb_temp_file_138942160_7753;trap "" INT QUIT TSTP;exec<&-; exec>&-;while :; do sleep 3600; done")
```

The `/tmp/edb_...` file doesn't stick around.  I guess edb just reads it to find out the path to the xterm's tty, and redirects the commands stdin/out to it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested with input+output but if you need to use a input file, you can build some kind of python "wrapper" as a one-liner. Works for me and is maybe not beautiful, but ok for my intentions:

```
python -c 'from time import sleep;sleep(20);a=open("input","r";content=a.read();print(content);a.close;'|./myapp
```

You now have 20 secs to run and attach edb. You can change sleep timer to your needs.
In another terminal you maybe want to run something like

```
edb --attach $(pidof myapp)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

There is a run button in EDB, you have to click that **twice** and a I/O terminal will open. Also the window where you ran edb will show you the TTY stream location. [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LrdF.jpg)

**Method 2**

If you want to redirect I/O of your binary "uppercaser" to a network port, you can use netcat tool (nc) do something like

1. Run "nc -nlvp 90 -e uppercaser"
2. Open edb debugger by running "edb"
3. In the GUI, File --> Attach
4. Select process "nc"
5. Now to the IO part, run "nc 127.0.0.1 90"
6. You now have your terminal open!

You can replace 90 with any other free port on your system.

Both methods worked well for me. If you are doing any sort of pentesting, i suggest you go with the second method

Comment: Are you sure you want to attach to the `nc` process?  Or does EDB trace into child processes when the listening netcat forks+execs `uppercaser`?

Comment: @PeterCordes EDB does trace into child processes when the listening netcat forks+execs! Actually I hav been breaking my head over this for the past 12 hours trying out all sorts of options. My problem was I couldnt paste all possible hex values into the terminal to figure out bad characters for a buffer overflow exploit. The method 2 mentioned above is the one that finally worked for me. I was successfully able to produce and analyse a segmentation fault of the child process!

Comment: Nifty.  If you just want to paste data into it, `mkfifo mypipe` might be what you want.  Then `testprog < mypipe &`, attach to it, then `(echo ...; cat) > mypipe`